# How do I move the start menu/task bar to a secondary or tertiary display as in a script or command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, display, script, taskbar

I have 4 monitors using Windows 10, and I am wondering if there's a way to move the task bar to another display using a script or command line. I know dragging is the easiest way to do it, but if there's a script, that would even be better.

What I'm not looking for is moving the task bar in different location on a the same display. It has to go onto another display.

Comment: *"I know dragging is the easiest way to do it, but if there's a script, that would even be better."*  So to clarify, you **don't** want to use the easiest method and something that is more difficult will actually be better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to script this without a 3rd party tool such as nircmd (download links are at the bottom of this page: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Basically, you can call this tool with:
`nircmd.exe setprimarydisplay X` (where X is any of your monitors 1 - 4)

and that display will become your primary display (and thus have your task bar).